# Windows Forms application lots of ambiguous symbols

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, directx-11

Creating a c++ forms application, I have started getting some ambiguous symbol errors. But I am not quite sure what from, it was compiling fine earlier but I may have changed something?

Thee error itself:

```
1>Application.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(4089): error C2872: 'IDropTarget': ambiguous symbol
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\oleidl.h(3508): note: could be 'IDropTarget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(4089): note: or       'System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(6496): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\servprov.h(98): note: could be 'IServiceProvider'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(6496): note: or       'System::IServiceProvider'
1>main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(4089): error C2872: 'IDropTarget': ambiguous symbol
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\oleidl.h(3508): note: could be 'IDropTarget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(4089): note: or       'System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(6496): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\servprov.h(98): note: could be 'IServiceProvider'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\ocidl.h(6496): note: or       'System::IServiceProvider'
```

I found this strange because my form isn't contained with any of these files, I assume it's that due to the namespacing. I just don't know where this is actually coming from.

Here is my form for info:

```
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class CFormController : public Form
{
public:
    CFormController(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ~CFormController()
    {
        delete components;
    }

    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container();
        this->Size = System::Drawing::Size(300, 300);
        this->Text = L"FormController";
        this->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(0);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
    }
};
```

The only other information about my form is in another class. Thats only used to display or hide it.

I found similar issues in that people didn't include the windows header before "using namespace..." but I added the include as you saw and it didn't make a difference whatsoever

Comment: This is **not** C++. This is C++/CLI. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: my apologies, I was unaware an extra tag was needed

Comment: No _extra_ tag was needed. As I previously mentioned - since this is **not** C++, C++ tag needed to be removed, and replaced with C++-cli tag, since it is, what the question is about - C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing conflicting symbols into the global namespace.

The code you posted should fine if it is the first file included in the compile unit. If that is not the case (e.g. you included another header file before the header file you posted) they you could have the WinForms types already present in the global namespace when you include windows.h, and causes C2872.

You can move the using statements or windows.h include into a namespace to avoid the conflict. 
e.g.

```
namespace Win32 {
#include "windows.h"
}
```

or

```
namespace ProjectName {

using namespace System;
......
}
```

Or if you really want to import the types into the global namespace, separate your code into two cpp files and import them one at a time.

Answer (score -1):

C++/CLI is notorious for symbol conflicts, whenever you are "using" many C# namespaces. Obviously, you have a conflict between System and System::Windows::Forms. Try to remove the latter "using" declaration, and specify symbols from this namespace by prefixing them with System::Windows::Forms::. I know this is a royal pain, but as far as I know there's no other workaround.

I face this problem regularly whenever I need classes from System::Collections::Generic.